# How can I display my python file in html?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, flask, debian

I'm using flask, tried different examples, many codes but nothing worked ..

this is my html:

```
<form method="post" name="prueba">

                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 control-label">Direccion IP: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ address }}" >
                             </div>
                         </div>
```

python file:

```
def get_info():

    with open('/etc/network/interfaces', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            found_address = line.find('address')
            if found_address != -1:
                address = line[found_address+len('address:'):]
                print 'Address: ', address
            found_network = line.find('network')
            if found_network != -1:
               network = line[found_network+len('network:'):]
               print 'Network: ', network
            found_netmask = line.find('netmask')
            if found_netmask != -1:
               netmask = line[found_netmask+len('netmask:'):]
               print 'Netmask: ', netmask 
            found_broadcast = line.find('broadcast')
            if found_broadcast != -1:
               broadcast = line[found_broadcast+len('broadcast:'):]
               print 'Broadcast: ', broadcast
    return address 
print get_info()

@app.route('/test')
def showPage():
    addresses = get_info()
    return render_template('test.html', addresses=addresses)
```

python file works correctly when I run it through console but when I try to display it inside my form nothing happens.

Comment: If it is more then 1 address, try to use {% for %}

Comment: I tried with {% for %} but nothing.

Comment: are you properly importing render_template? Are having any errors when trying to browse in the /test route?

Comment: No, it's working fine in the /test route. I don't know why I can't display my address inside my form. Maybe it's not opening /etc/network/interfaces correctly from my project?

Comment: try to put some html inside {% if addresses %} {% endif %} to see if the template engine is recognizing this variable. Remember to use the same name you pass, in this case addresses, not address

Comment: just tested your code, and it works with my example file (it contains address 192 ... network and broadcast in separated lines). im not sure, but maybe you are running multiple flask instances at same time and it can cause this problem. (task manager or top in unix and close all pythonw instances)

Comment: @JánosFarkas did you test my code exactly as it is? with addresses = getinfo()?

Comment: i tested it as it is in original post (addresses = get_info())

Comment: try closing all the pythonw instances (or restart your comp) it should help.

Comment: @JánosFarkas not working :/

Comment: this is my demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jwtomhy1qprybuw/flask.zip?dl=0
i hope its helpful (its working on my pc)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you provide the data to the template as `addresses` but you call the variable in your template `address`?